# what is Algorithm or function hash password in membership asp.net 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I want to create custom membership for my website, but I do not want to use ASP.NET Membership.

I want to use a hashed password in my custom membership, similar to the hashed password in ASP.NET Membership.

Is the following code correct and best?

```
public string EncodePassword(string pass, string salt)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
    byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);
    byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];

    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);

    HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
    byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}
```

Comment: It might be if sha1 were still reliable. But sha1 is not reliable any more.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Please help me for Algorithm is reliable

Comment: Having the same problem here, that code is no longer valid